# pandas groupby with aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this code:

```
october_data_grouped = october_data.groupby(["Department", "Headcount", "Day"]).agg({'User ID': 'nunique'})
october_data_grouped.unstack(fill_value=0)
```

And this gives the output below:

[image]

Is there a way I can make a calculation that each individual entry is divided by the headcount [e.g. for row Accounts, day 1 would be 17% (6/35), day 4 would be 25% (9/35) etc.]

Comment: Please see [ask] and don't post images of text

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
#for avoid MultiIndex in columns
october_data_grouped = (october_data.groupby(["Department", "Headcount", "Day"])['User ID']
                                    .nunique()
                                    .unstack(fill_value=0))

idx = october_data_grouped.index.get_level_values('Headcount')
october_data_grouped = october_data_grouped.div(idx, axis=0)
```

Comment: works great, and how can i also add an average for each row at the end of the table ? thank you !

Comment: @GabrielBouKaram - Use `october_data_grouped['avg'] = october_data_grouped.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: great, thanks a lot!